# How to process the JSON data send to a PHP file via Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have a php file where user will fill the form and the form data will be send to the backend php file in JSON format but i am unable to retrieve the JSON data send to the php file

// DATA SENDING ...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#submit').click(function () {
                var name, id, sec, base;
                name = $('#name').val();
                id = $('#id').val();
                sec = $('#pay').val();
                base = [{name: name, reg: id, sec: sec}];
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/post/json.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: JSON.stringify(base),
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    async: false,
                    success: function (json) {
                        //do something ... after the data successfully processed via json.php 
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

i tried to write the php as simple file to get query string and echoing it but nothing happen ... but if i POST simple query string (via jQuery) then its echoing

// PHP BACKEND

```
<?php
  $ar= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];    
  echo $ar;
?>
```

Comment: You have the two built in functions json_decode and json_encode to work with json in php. Is it not enough?

Comment: POST data is sent as HTTP body not as query string..use $_POST in PHP

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty i used it already but nothing happened

Answer (score 0):

Please read this page: [Get JSON object from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15617512/get-json-object-from-url)

```
$json = file_get_contents('url_here'); 
$obj = json_decode($json); echo
$obj->access_token;
```

also `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];` won't work because you send data via POST.

use `$_POST['base']` instead.

Comment: i firstly used $_POST['name']; etc to echo the data but it didnt work

Comment: Use `$_POST['base']`, not name

Answer (score 0):

You are using **POST** as request type, therefore all data submitted `('name', 'red', 'sec')` is available in the pre-defined `$_POST` array.

Also, your JavaScript could be simplified:

```
var name = $('#name').val();
var id = $('#id').val();
var sec = $('#pay').val();
$.post( "/post/json.php", {name: name, reg: id, sec: sec}, function( data ) {
    ...
});
```

Comment: $data=$_POST['name'];
this is also unable to echo the data 
echo $data

Answer (score 0):

You need to get POST data, this will not append as a query string,
try to use $_POST or send it to a variable via post.

Try to use:

```
data: { base : JSON.stringify(base)},
// or data:'base =' + JSON.stringify(base),
```

Then get it on php file

```
$data = json_decode($_POST['base']);
```

For more: [How to send json string to a php file using jquery submit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9239155/how-to-send-json-string-to-a-php-file-using-jquery-submit)

Answer (score 0):

You are using the http POST request to submit the data on server which is accessible via
`$_POST` superglobal array.

`$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` will be useful if you use http GET request.

simply use `$_POST['name']`, `$_POST['reg']` etc. to access submitted data.

Comment: firstly i used so ... but $_POST[name]; etc..  also didn't work for me so i use $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] but nothing achieved yet

Comment: Please change this in your jquery code  `data: "jsondata="+JSON.stringify(base);` and access it on server side using `$jsonArray = json_decode($_POST['jsondata']);` Then you can access required data using `$jsonArray['name']`

Answer (score 0):

You can try it

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#submit').click(function () {
    ....
    base = {name: name, reg: id, sec: sec};
        $.ajax({
            ...
            data: base,
            dataType: 'json',
            ...
        });
    });
});
```

And your php BACKEND

```
$post = json_decode($_POST);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not used post data key, the JSON data will be posted into single key,

Change

```
  data: JSON.stringify(base)
```

to

```
data: "json="+JSON.stringify(base)
```

And get data on server

```
print_r(json_decode($_POST['json']));
```

Comment: @SoumeshBanerjee did you check in ajax request firebug console..?

Comment: yes the params are successfully passed but no response is received from the server 
but if i just echo 'ok'; in backend then it respond ok when the file is invoked